# Duplicate in list

Tags: list, duplicate-management

I am trying to update SObject record depending on the crtieria, id it matches create a SObject variable and adding values and then finally adding this into a List.When a match is found the Sobject variable here'PRrecordupdate' gets created and values get assigend but as I add it in a list,the original value already present in the list is removed and this latest PRrecordupdate get saved multiple times.
Please look into the code below and let me know what I am doing wrong.Thanks

```
 List<Domain_review__C> newPR = new List<Domain_review__C>();
List<Domain_review__C> PRCollectionupdate = new List<Domain_review__C>();
Domain_review__C PRrecordupdate = new Domain_review__C();  
map<id,domain_review__C> PRmap = new map<id,domain_review__C>();    

List<Domain_Review__c> PR  =  [Select id,name,Property_Name_text__c from Domain_Review__c Where Exchange_Quality_ID__c =: a0W56000002PgXfEAK];

        For(domain_review__c a: PR)
        {
            
            For(Domain_review__c b: newPR)
            
            {
                               
                if(a.Property_Name_text__c == b.property_text__c)
                {
                   
                    
                    PRrecordupdate.Id = a.Id;
                    PRrecordupdate.Approval_Status__c = b.Approval_Status__c;
                    PRrecordupdate.Rejection_Reason__c = b.Rejection_Reason__c;
                    PRrecordupdate.seller_name__c = b.seller_name__c;
                    PRrecordupdate.Inventory_Relationship__c = b.Inventory_Relationship__c;
                    
                    
                    PRCollectionupdate.add(PRrecordupdate);
//?? here, it's removing the earlier record and updating with new record multiple times, means at the end in PRCollectionupdate list only one record is saved multiple times//
                  

                }
                
            }

               }
     
        
       
       PRmap.putall(PRCollectionupdate);
      
if(PRmap.size()>0){
    update PRmap.values();
}
```

Comment: You want `Set<Domain_review__C> PRCollectionupdate..` and no need for a map at the end, convert the set to a list for DML update statement. Try this tutorial:  https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/object-oriented-programming-for-admins/define-sets-and-maps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is in PRCollectionupdate duplicate values getting saved.It take the last iteration values and saves it multiple times(whenever if criteria is executed).It saves the same record.

Comment: since you don't have an Order By in your SOQL, results will be indeterminate over time as which record wins out is unpredictable

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some missing pieces of information here. You're instantiating an empty List called newPR and then trying to iterate over it

```
List<Domain_review__C> newPR = new List<Domain_review__C>();
//...
For(Domain_review__c b: newPR)
//...
```

It seems like you want some kind of order, but not clear what. The SOQL seems like it needs an ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC (or DESC if you want latest). But I think what might drive you here is doing away with the PRCollectionupdate variable altogether and just use the PRmap.

Instead of this:

```
PRCollectionupdate.add(PRrecordupdate);
```

Try this:

```
            if(!PRmap.getKey(PRrecordupdate.Id)){
                PRmap.put(PRrecordupdate.Id, PRrecordupdate);                    
            }
            else{
                //do something when the record already exists in the Map
                //like check another value such as when it was created   
            }
```

then get rid of "PRMap.putall(PRCollectionupdate)"